# Making an API call with every Angular ng-click

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm new to web development and can't seem to find the answer to this question anywhere. I want my NodeJS API endpoint to be called with every ng-click, not just when the page gets loaded. Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="myFunction()">Click me!</button>
```

Angular:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.post("/test").then(function(response) {
        $scope.testString = response.data;
    });
});
```

NodeJS

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    console.log("test get");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="myFunction()">Click me!</button>
```

Angular:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.myFunction = function() {
      $http.post("/test").then(function(response) {
          $scope.testString = response.data;
      });
    }
});
```